# Is there more elegant way than using if - else to append or update the data array in a React app?

Tags: javascript, react.js

Below is a React useEffect hook I used in my application, basically what it does is:

`data` is an array for objects such as `{round:number, date:dateString}`.

When the application starts running, `data` will be an empty array, whenever `round` gets updated, the `useEffect()` will be called:

1. if the `data` array is empty, we update it with its very first object.
2. else the `data` array is not empty and if the last object of data array has its date property equal to `props.localeDate`, I make a new array with the its last object updated
3. else the data array is not empty and else the last object's date property is not equal to `props.localeDate`, I append a new object to data array.

---

```
const Chart = ({ round, dateAndTime }) => {      
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const localeDate = dateAndTime.toLocaleDateString();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data.length === 0) {
      setData([
        ...data,
        {
          round: round,
          date: localeDate,
        },
      ]);
    } else {
      //update item if date matches
      if (data[data.length - 1].date === localeDate) {
        let newData = data.map((item) => {
          let newItem =
            item.date === localeDate ? { ...item, round: round } : item;
          return newItem;
        });
        setData(newData);
      } else {
        setData([...data, { round: round, date: localeDate }]);
      }
    }
  }, [round]);
 return (jsx element);
}
```

My code works as expected, but I am wondering if there is any way to improve on it? Using if-else looks really ugly.

Comment: @BCdotWEB, true, thanks. Updated as per your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you do the *same thing* if the array is empty or if the last item's `localeDate` doesn't match - you can combine those two paths.

You only want to update the existing object if the last item exists and its date matches, so I'd first set a flag for that, which can be done concisely via optional chaining.

Then, `.map` looks a bit verbose when all items of the array are unchanged *except for one* - you could consider using `.slice` instead to take all but the last item, spread them into a new array, then add the changed object as the last item.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // update item if date matches
    const changeExistingItem = data[data.length - 1]?.date === localeDate;
    const updatedData = changeExistingItem
        ? [...data.slice(0, data.length - 1), { ...data[data.length - 1], round }]
        : [...data, { round, date: localeDate }];
    setData(updatedData);
}, [round]);
```

Also see that you can use shorthand property names to keep things concise: `{ someProp: someProp` simplifies to `{ someProp` in modern Javascript.

As a side note: [always use `const`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) to declare variables, whenever possible. When you use `let`, you're warning readers of the code that you *may be reassigning* that variable name in the future, which results in more cognitive overhead.